# Issues getting div to float right of another div

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I am trying to get my registerbutton div to float right of the div - signinbutton. I do not think I can wrap the signin div around the register div to make it a parent because I have pop up code under the signinbutton div. I tried making a jsfiddle, but the effect did not result the same. To see a real view of this, my site is sundayfundayleague.com .

I need to get the register button to be inline with the Sign in one.

HTML

```
<div class="signinbutton"> 
    <a class="signin" href="javascript:void(0)">Sign In</a>
</div>
<div class="registerbutton">
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.signinbutton {
   padding: 10px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    margin-top: 325px;
    margin-left: 30%;
}
.registerbutton {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    margin-right: 30%;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use span inside the 1st div

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/knkvksdz/

**Html**

```
<div class="signinbutton"> <a class="signin" href="javascript:void(0)">Sign In</a>

<span class="registerbutton">
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>
</span>

</div>
```

**Css**

```
.signinbutton {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    margin-top: 325px;
    margin-left: 30%;
}
.registerbutton {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: This mostly worked, except it made my register part HUGE. How can I stop that from happening?

Comment: @Becky -- take out  --  padding: 10px; -- and  -- font-size: 2.5em; -- like you see above in my answer for (.registerbutton). looks ok to me after that

Comment: Great, that fixed that. How can I get the `margin-right: 30%;` to work for the register button. It is scaling it over some, but it seems like it is half of what is should be.

Comment: @becky you mean you want the register to be closer to signin a little bit??

Comment: Yes, I want them to be equally 30% from the outer margins of my parent div - homeimg div.

Comment: @becky -- well then you need to get rid of the float:right; and just have --   margin-left: 20%; -- that is the margin to the left from the signinbutton  so no need to float -- increase or decrease the % to get it right

Answer (score 1):

First of all. Try reducing your picture size. its too big. i takes time to load the page.

Here is my solution.

I will add wrapper outside those two.

```
 <div class="wrapper">  
    <div class="signinbutton"> 
        <a class="signin" href="javascript:void(0)">Sign In</a>
    </div>
    <div id="light" class="signInpopup">
        <a class="close" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a>

        <form id="signInform" name="Sign In" action="" method="POST" autocomplete="on" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <div class="center">

                <input type="text" name="username" id="signInInput" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="on" required="">
                <br>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="signInPasswordInput" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required="">
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <label for="remember">
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">Remember me</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="token" value="687d55402565d69c55ab41c51eba5d76">
                <label for="widebutton">
                    <input id="widebutton" type="submit" value="Sign In">
                </label>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>

    <div class="registerbutton">
         <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and add this css to wrapper:

```
.wrapper{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   margin-top: 50px;
}
```

remove this from your #registerbutton

```
 float:right
```

and remove from your .signinbutton

```
 margin-top:352px;
```

and add .signinbutton

```
 float:left
```

Comment: My bad. you should add .signinbutton with float:left. @Becky

Answer (score 1):

flip the divs around in the HTML code and use the float: left; attribute instead. Float right tends to be a bit more tricky I think and float left is the more complient one. You might have better luck doing it that way.

```
<div class="registerbutton">
<a href="register.php">Register</a>
</div>
<div class="signinbutton"> 
<a class="signin" href="javascript:void(0)">Sign In</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.registerbutton {
padding: 10px;
font-size: 2.5em;
margin-right: 30%;
}

.signinbutton {
padding: 10px;
font-size: 2.5em;
margin-top: 325px;
margin-left: 30%;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: take out the margin-left and margin-right attributes.

What I'm aiming to accomplish with this is the div you want right will be stacked on the top, not on the bottom, so when you use float left on the one on the bottom it will float to the left and the one you want on the right will be on the right by default.

It really should work.